# I have created a table view programmatically as follows-

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    menuArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Address",@"Restaurants",@"Deals",@"Orders",@"Account",@"Address Book",@"Settings",@"Live Chat",@"Info",nil];
    tableView=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, menuSubView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width-80, self.view.frame.size.height-menuSubView.frame.size.height)];
    tableView.delegate=self;
    tableView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

and other methods as follows-

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return menuArray.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *reusableIdentifier=@"Cell4";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reusableIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reusableIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 70;
}
```

However when I run the program i am able to see the table view as desired. But when I scroll through it, table's data disappear and only blank table view remains. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: put a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check after scrolling the table how the table view is behaving after reloading

Comment: It Seems you did well, your label's color is white?

Comment: I tried putting a breakpoint at cellForRowAtIndexPath it works fine till the table is created completely. but once I reload the table, pointer does not go back at cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh no, it is default (black). if it were a colour issue i wouldn't have seen it for the first time itself.

Comment: If possible upload your file to dropBox and add the link in the comments section.

Comment: @MdIbrahimHassan  please find the below links-    https://www.dropbox.com/s/uyjp9ledmnecexl/MenuViewViewController.m?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgspkmaysoohej9/MenuViewViewController.h?dl=0

Comment: get back to you in 5-10 mins

Comment: It is working fine for me without any modifications of your code. Just delete the app and re-run.

Answer (score 1):

--> I appreciate above answer.

--> Please try this line in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" Method...!

--> Sometimes it happens. I have solved this issue with this line in past. I hope it's useful for you.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell4" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: I did try this also, but the problem is that if I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier::forIndexPath, it gives me an error saying that " You must register a class or nib for the identifier". I read about that error and found that removing :forIndexPath worked out for that error but I started getting this issue.